# VBA Makro Save as csv

Tags: vba

I want to write an VBA makro to save selected excel sheets as csv files. What did I collect up to know:

```
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SaveToDirectory As String

Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
Dim CurrentFormat As Long

CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat

  SaveToDirectory = "G:\...\Create csv\" & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & "_csv Save" & "\"

  If Len(Dir(SaveToDirectory, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir SaveToDirectory
  End If

  For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If WS.Name = "Government_debt" Or WS.Name = "Domestic_demand" Or (...) Then
        WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name, xlCSV
    End If
  Next
```

**What do I need to complete it?**

1. I need the time after the date, in case I need to run the makro twice a day.
   `"YYYYMMDDHHMM"` as solution gives me `201504280000`
2. I want to create the directory in that way, that it is the folder of the file, in which the makro is. I tried already `CurDir()` and `Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path` but without success
3. I want to exclude some excel sheets instead of choosing only the ones to save. E.g I have some sheets "calc_(...)" which I do not need. How can I do that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the macro in the same spreadsheet as the sheets you are saving as CSVs? If so the macro file is ThisWorkbook not ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: To save sheets that do NOT start with "calc_", you can use the loop `If Not WS.Name Like "calc_*" Then (...)`.  That way you don't have to do a ton or `OR` statements with the sheet names you want.

Comment: thanks, I forgot about the other way how to create the loop.

Comment: "No, unfortunately not" Well per my previous comment that could explain your issue #2. And macros not being in the same spreadsheet usually **better** design than combining them (and with limited info seems so here). So I wouldn't say "unfortunately."